# Visibility of Connectify notification icon on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, powershell, connectify

I'm currently needing to frequently connect my Windows 10 (Version 1511, OS Build 10586.318) laptop to the internet via my cable-tethered Samsung Android phone. Every time I've happened to power-cycle my laptop, Windows 10 decides to rename my Samsung phone to `Network xx`, eg `Network 27` was the last one. Each time this happens, my [Connectify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectify_Hotspot) [System Tray Icon](http://lifehacker.com/how-to-customize-the-system-tray-icons-in-windows-10-1724097781) gets hidden, and I have to go throught this sequence (using mouse pointer or touch-screen):

```
Settings > System > Notification & actions > Select which icons appear on the taskbar > Connectify Hotspot > On
```

Having done this now 27 times, I'd really like to find a PowerShell script or something to do this for me, but can't find any clues as to how to proceed.